# Can't host Discord Bot on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, discord.js

I did everything in the tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=758&v=kpci6V8969g). When I run the pm2 command, the bot doesn't work.
When I try the node index.js command, it displays me this error:

```
async setProvider(provider) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

Comment: What version of node do you have installed? You can find out by doing `node -v`

Comment: To be honest i don't know, becouse it's discord.js-commando framwork.
On windows it works.

Comment: I installed node v6.14.2

Comment: Having looked up similar issues, the common fix seems to be installing Node v8 or higher. You can try a newer version from here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial may not have been what you needed. From my experience, all you have to do is install `node.js` and `Node Package Manager` or `NPM` for short. Both of these I use exclusively. A quick google search can bring you many tutorials on youtube and on various other tech websites that are sure to help. I hope this helps

Wishing you luck,

Zaedus